# Program not working - python

Tags: python

This program does not work and sends an error on line 6 and 8.Ty for any help

> line 6 IndexError: list index out of range line 8, in 
>       print(plane_ride_cost("Tampa"))

```
list=["Charlotte","Tampa","Pittsburgh","Los Angeles"]
list2=[(20,11,23,56)]
def plane_ride_cost(city):
        for i in range (4):
            if city == list[i]:
                return list2[i]

print(plane_ride_cost("Tampa"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the site tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn about the site and then take a look at [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first off, make sure to never use a variable name that clashes with a built-in method name (list)

```
my_list=["Charlotte","Tampa","Pittsburgh","Los Angeles"]
my_list2=[20,11,23,56]

def plane_ride_cost(city): 
    for i in range(4): 
        if city == my_list[i]: 
            return my_list2[i]
```

Another problem is you have the list2 only have one index all inside of a single tuple.
So when range is anything other than 0 it will never be able to print anything from list2.

My code above works, and should make more sense.

And in the future try to put your code in a snippet, and follow the rules as the other user posted.

Comment: Thanks for your help!